GCP private VPC connection with external sql server
I have set up the private environment to connect onPrem sql server to gcp datafusion. Datafusion uses sql server's connector to fetch the data into data fusion.
Here are my setup details:
I have a private data fusion instance with ip(10.20.160.0/22)
I have a vpc private with subnets in range(10.20.160.0/24)
There is a router and NAT which has an external ip address to communicate with the internet(35.x.x.x).
The firewall rules are all set properly.
The ip address (35.x.x.x) is whitelisted on the onPrem sql server machine.
But I am still getting this error:
SQL error while getting query schema: The TCP/IP connection to the host 178.x.171.36, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
Everything was working as expected but it stopped suddenly.
How can i fix the issue, Do I need to add any additional configs?
Is there any guide that uses the same configurations for data migration?

How technically your request know it has to go to the internet, and reach your on-prem env and, when on your on prem env, reach your 178xxxx ip? Nothing impossible, but you need to define route, wrappers, or VPN to achieve this. From your description, it sounds simply impossible!

@guillaumeblaquiere I dont have much idea, I am new on this project but it stopped working for some reason. Is there any guide that can help me in troubleshoot this issue?

Also, I am passing the sql server's credentials requested in data fusion and 178.x.x.x is the host in this case but 35.x.x.x is the public ip address reserved in the NAT settings in gcp
